# Upload/download pdf files in SQL Server using mvc 2010

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, pdf

I've been learning on my own how to program in **c#** with **mvc 2010 Express**, as I've been asked to create an application for the company I work for.
The last thing I have to do is allow the users to **upload and download a pdf** file and I can't find a solution that helps me.

I use **SQL Server 2005**. The table I want to use is called `Clients`. It has an `Id` as the primary key. Should I create an attribute to store the pdf as a binary file? Or how?

To upload the pdf I have a link in my view that redirects the user to another view (named Upload) with the `id` of the client. The controller name is `Home`, so the user will see something like:

```
Home.aspx/Upload/2
```

There, I want the user to be able to select the pdf he wants to upload and then click the button to upload it. So the controller will handle it with the `[HttpPost]`.

To edit a client it was pretty straight forward, as I created Model Views in the folder ViewModels and then passed them to the controller.
But **how can I pass to the controller both the `id` and the pdf file?** I need the `id` to know what user is that. And **how can I store the pdf in my table `Clients` in SQL Server?**
And then **how can I download the pdf?**

Comment: This should really be several questions, all of which can already be found on SO

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is what i'm using...you should do some changes to adapt it to your requirements.

> *how can I pass to the controller both the id and the pdf file?*

**View:**

```
  @using (Html.BeginForm("Add", "Archivos",
                     FormMethod.Post, new { id = "attachment", enctype = "multipart/form-data", encoding = "multipart/form-data" }))
    { 


        @Html.HiddenFor(x => Model.UserID)
        <input type="file" name="uploadFile" id="uploadFile" />

       <input type="submit" value="Guardar"/>

    }
```

**Controller:**

```
   [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Add(HttpPostedFileBase uploadFile, int UserID)
    {
        if (uploadFile != null && uploadFile.ContentLength > 0)
        {

            //instance the user.. i.e "User1"

            byte[] tempFile = new byte[uploadFile.ContentLength];
            uploadFile.InputStream.Read(tempFile, 0, uploadFile.ContentLength);

            User1.file.Content = tempFile;
            User1.file.Save();

        }

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

> *And then how can I download the pdf?*

**Controller:**

```
public ActionResult Get(int UserID)
    { 

        var User1 = new User {UserID = UserID };
        User1.LoadFile();

   //If file exists....

        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(User1.File.Content, 0, 0, true, true);
        Response.ContentType = User1.File.Type;
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" + User1.File.Name);
        Response.Buffer = true;
        Response.Clear();
        Response.OutputStream.Write(ms.GetBuffer(), 0, ms.GetBuffer().Length);
        Response.OutputStream.Flush();
        Response.End();
        return new FileStreamResult(Response.OutputStream, User1.File.Type);

    }
```

**View:**

```
    @Html.ActionLink("PDF", "Get", "Files", new { UserID = Model.UserID }, new { @class = "pdf-icon-l", title="Open PDF document" })
```

> *And how can I store the pdf in my table Clients in SQL Server?*

**Database Table:**

```
 CREATE TABLE [dbo].[FileTableName] (
 [UserID] int NOT NULL,
 [Name] varchar(256) NOT NULL,
 [Type] varchar(256) NOT NULL,
 [Length] int NOT NULL,
 [Content] varchar(max) NOT NULL) // option: varbinary(max)
```

To store the files I'm using a Stored Procedure

**Model:**

```
 public class File
 {

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public long Length { get; set; }
    public byte[] Content { get; set; }

}

public class User

{
    public int UserID {get; set;}
    public string name {get; set;}
    /**/

    public file file {get; set;}


    /**/

    public void SaveFile()
   {
    SqlDataReader _dataReader;
    using (new MyConnectionManager())
    {
        using (_sqlCommand = new SqlCommand("SavePDFFile", MyConnectionManager.Connection)) 
       {
        _sqlCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        _sqlCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@UserID", this.UserID));
        _sqlCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Name", this.Name));
        _sqlCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Type", this.Type));
        _sqlCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Length", this.Length));
        _sqlCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Content", this.Content));
        _dataReader = _sqlCommand.ExecuteReader();

        _dataReader.Close();
    }
  }
}

  public void LoadFile()
    { 
        SqlDataReader _dataReader;
        using (new MyConnectionManager())
        {
             using (_sqlCommand = new SqlCommand("GetPDFFIle", MyConnectionManager.Connection))
            _sqlCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            _sqlCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@UserID", this.IDEnsayo));
            _dataReader = _sqlCommand.ExecuteReader();
            if (_dataReader.HasRows)
            {
                _dataReader.Read();
                this.File.Name = (string)_dataReader["Name"];
                this.File.Type = (string)_dataReader["Type"];
                this.File.Length = (int)_dataReader["Length"];
                this.File.Content = (byte[])_dataReader["Content"];

            }
            _dataReader.Close();
        }
    }
  }

 }
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I will try everything this Monday. 
I really appreciate that you spent some time reading and answering my question and so detailed!

Comment: I have a few questions...  
In the controller of the first view, why does it recognise UserId?
The table where you are storing the pdfs is called `User`or `file`?  
And I've never used stored procedures yet. Where are you telling the controller that you want to use `Save`to store the pdf? Is it what you called `SaveFile` up in the controller?  
Sorry for so many questions but I am a little bit lost.

Comment: _In the controller of the first view, why does it recognise UserId?_ because you are posting the form. In this case the file and the ID filed. _The table where you are storing the pdfs is called User or file?_ this is an example. It will depend that your model. In my system, it is call: "TestFile". _Where are you telling the controller that you want to use Saveto store the pdf? Is it what you called SaveFile up in the controller?_ Yeap. I will update my answer.

Comment: Yes, I know it is an example but I want to understand it perfectly in order to come up with a solution that fits me...
I asked the wrong question. Why do you do `User1.file.Content`? Isn't `Content`in `TestFile`? I thought that you have a table called `User` and with the id you "created" `User1` which is of type `User`. But I don't understand what is `file` then. Can you tell me the structure you have for those tables?

Comment: Does storing a pdf in `varchar(max)` work? I would have thought that should be a `varbinary` column.

Comment: @Bridge It should work. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4598529/which-data-type-for-storing-images-and-documents-in-sql-server-2005

Comment: @Pabloker 3/4 of the answers there agree with me ;-)

Comment: @Bridge I just added your suggestion to the answer. Thanks.

Comment: Quick question! in your `ActionResult Get`, at the end, in the line you say what to return (`return new FileStreamResult(Response.OutputStream, User1.File.Content);`), instead of the content `User1.File.Content`, shouldn't it be the type of the file? (`User1.File.Type`)

Comment: Yes. It's true. I just changed that. Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried to get the file?I can't make it work...
So far I have something like: 
`public ActionResult Get(int id)
{ var file = dre.tClientsFiles.First(m => m.IdFile == id);
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(file.Content, 0, 0, true, true);
Response.ContentType = file.Type;
Response,AddHeader("content-disposition","attachment;filename=" + file.Name);`
...etc -> Its amost the same to yours but with file.TheAttributeYouWant,as I obtained `file` from the consult I made at the beginning.
It opens (or downloads)a blank file(the tittle, type and lenght are ok)
Do you know what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Yep, it works. Are you sure that the file is stored correctly?

Comment: oh I just realized my mistake! I stored the lenght in Kb and then I didn't change it back to bytes so when it tried to retrieve it it was doing it with the wrong one!
Thanks A LOT for all your help!