# Unable to retrieve the size of the pdf files in a folder

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

Unable to retrieve the size of the pdf files in a folder, this code below returns me with a null column in the table and I also wanted to know if I could store both file name and size in one table it self.

```
  Create table #PDFFiles

(
            PDFFile varchar(300)
)

Declare @param as varchar(100)
Declare @Path as varchar(1000)
Declare @PreparedBatch as Nvarchar(max);

Set @PreparedBatch =
            'DECLARE @pdf pdf
            SELECT @pdf = CAST(BulkColumn AS pdf)
            FROM OPENROWSET(BULK ''?'', SINGLE_BLOB) AS x
            INSERT dbo.PDFDocument (PDFdoc)
                        SELECT @pdf;';
 Set @Path = 'C:\dump\'
Set @param = 'dir ' + @Path + '*.pdf /b'

Insert into #PDFFiles
Exec master..xp_cmdshell @param
Update #PDFFiles Set PDFFile = @Path + PDFFile


While Exists(select * from #PDFFiles where PDFFile is not null)
Begin
            Declare @CurrentFile Table (PDFFile varchar(300));

            Delete Top (1) from #PDFFiles
            OUTPUT DELETED.PDFFile INTO @CurrentFile
            Where PDFFile is not null

            Declare @Batch as Varchar(max)
            Select @Batch = Replace(@PreparedBatch,'?',PDFFile)  from @CurrentFile    
            Exec (@Batch)
            Delete from @CurrentFile
End
```

This is the error I am getting when running this code

```
Column, parameter, or variable #1: Cannot find data type pdf.
Parameter or variable '@pdf' has an invalid data type.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no pdf data type:

`DECLARE @pdf pdf`

That should be VARBINARY or FILESTREAM

[Which data-type for storing images and documents in SQL Server 2005](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4598529/which-data-type-for-storing-images-and-documents-in-sql-server-2005)

Comment: When I change that to varbinary i get this error
Type pdf is not a defined system type.

Comment: you have that definition in multiple places:  `SELECT @pdf = CAST(BulkColumn AS pdf)`